# Nvidia Tesla K20 and video output

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I have a workstation with Nvidia GTX 590, used for CUDA development, however since the release of new Tesla double-precision enabled K20 I was thinking about an upgrade.

My question is, does this card, or any other in the Tesla line for that matter, allow for video output to a single monitor? Or should I rather put it in as a secondary card for development and keep 590 (or something else) for the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should keep the 590 and put the GK110-based GPU as a dedicated compute card.